# When selecting a date how can I keep the datepicker open?

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have an Angular 4.x app that uses the Angular Material Datepicker (package.json shows this as `"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12"`) - I have got this working fine however I require the ability to select a date and keep the datepicker open - this functionality is available in the following release of Angular Material (v5.0.0) however it also would mean upgrading our version of Angular itself from 4 to 5 (something which we are unable to do currently at this time)

How can I amend the code to allow me to either a) keep the datepicker open even once a date selection has been made OR b) once the date selection has been made instantly re-open the datepicker - is this possible using this older version of material

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysspzm-bz2ezu?file=app/datepicker-overview-example.ts

// HTML Component

```
<mat-datepicker-toggle
        matSuffix
        [for]="picker">
</mat-datepicker-toggle>

<mat-datepicker
        #picker
        class="fixed-open"
        opened="true">
</mat-datepicker>
```

// Custom Datepicker Component
imports added here...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker.component.scss']
})

export class DatepickerComponent {
  @ViewChild('keepOpen') _input: ElementRef;

  _openCalendar(picker: MatDatepicker<Date>) {
      picker.open();
  }
}
```

// The `datepicker.d.ts` from the node_modules directory (I am using the code below in the pastebin link)
https://pastebin.com/ChYBmpU6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work on date change, you could refactor this to any event type you need.

Component

```
 @ViewChild('picker') picker;

  _openCalendar() {
   setTimeout(()=>this.picker.open());
  }
```

HTML

```
<input 
      matInput 
      [matDatepicker]="picker" 
      placeholder="Choose a date" 
      (dateChange)="_openCalendar()"
      #keepOpen>
```

Comment: Good shot - the dateChange picks up the selection but doesn't keep the datepicker open - I am starting to think I may have to just upgrade my Angular Material (which won't be fun)

Comment: Well this solution programmatically reopens the datepicker in your stackblitz example once a date is selected, did I miss understand your requirement?

Comment: don't forget the setTimeout wrapper, you need this for it to work.

Comment: The one thing it will not do is reopen it if the same date is selected, the date has to change. You will need to probably leverage a different event type to overcome this.

Comment: I will have another look at the example in stackblitz i'm probably tired and made a mistake :)